# Exam class with variations using exsheets

Tags: exam, exsheets

When I make an exam with 2 variations and add a points table at the end it considers that the exam has twice the number of questions.

How can you stop this from happening automatically?

Comment: Member for more than 3 years without an MWE? Please add it!

Comment: what is an MWE?

Comment: are you really using [`exam`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exam) together with [`exsheets`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exsheets)?

Comment: [Minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Yes I am @clemens. Is that the problem?

Comment: @Concept7 I have no idea (but I always thought of the two as alternatives to each other)

Comment: That might be true @clemens. I just found the exsheets package today and I'm learning and testing.

Comment: @Concept7 if you just found it today then I would suggest not using `exsheets` but instead have a look at [`xsim`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xsim)

Comment: oh :D thanks a lot @clemens! would have been a few more years until I found that one... and then there would be another.

Comment: @Concept7 - did you ever find an answer to your question? I have the same question. I looked at xism too but don't see a \vary option.